# code not working for advent of code 2020 day 2 part 1

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop, nested-lists

my output wasn't the answer and I also had the valids list to check all the valids and I can confirm that my way of checking if something is valid is most definitely wrong, but I don't know how to fix it

the question: https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/2

my output is 450 and this is the puzzle input: https://pastebin.com/MBHaMr7m

```
#Day 2 part 1
count = 0
valid = 0
#valids = []

with open('inputs\input2.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.replace(" ", "")
    data = data.replace("-", "")
    data = data.replace(":", "")

data = [str(x) for x in data.splitlines()]
data = [list(x) for x in data]

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in data[i][3:]:
        if data[i][2] == j:
            count += 1

        if count >= int(data[i][0]) and count <= int(data[i][1]):
            valid += 1
            #valids.append(data[i])
            count = 0

        else:
            count = 0    

#print(valids)
print(valid)
```

When I printed valids, the passwords were all invalid, my way of checking if it is correct is most likely wrong and I still can't figure out what is wrong with my code, please help.
(couldnt find a good title for the question btw)

Comment: Posting a link to your input is not useful because we are not logged in as you.

Comment: @khelwood how do i send my input then? and the input format is the same anyway if im not wrong

Comment: Your parsing is broken. The first field is not necessarily exactly 3 characters, unlike in the sample input. You can't simply remove all spaces, `-`, and `:` from the input.

Comment: Here's an example from my own input: `14-16 b: bbbbbbbbbbbbbtbbb`.

Comment: Why can't I remove all spaces and stuff

Comment: Consider my example. If you remove all the spaces and such first, you are left with `1416bbbbbbbbbbbbbbtbbb`. While you can infer the character is `b` and the password is `bbbbbbbbbbbbbtbbb`, you can no longer reconstruct the correct range. Is that `1-416` or `14-16`?

Comment: Ah I see, so what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Process each line as you read it, using things like `str.split` or `re.match` to pick out  each field instead of erasing the field delimiters immediately.

Comment: Ok I will try it and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

You are making invalid assumptions about the input, in particular that each range consists of two single-digit numbers. Try something like

```
with open(r'inputs\input2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lowhigh, character, password = line.strip().split()
        low, high = lowhigh.split('-')
        low = int(low)
        high = int(high)

        # Now check if <character> occurs between <low> and <high> times in <password>
```

Comment: i made new code but it doesn't work, yes i did the parsing thing the same way as you but it still doesn't work, the output is too small (my output is 3)

Comment: this is my pastebin code: https://pastebin.com/fjsTxArq

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it, I just had to reset count after each check